# Why cancelAcquire() of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer set node.next=node?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I am reading the source code of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer? I found that the method cancelAcquire() is a bit difficult to understand, THE LAST LINE CONFUSE ME:

```
private void cancelAcquire(Node node) {
        // Ignore if node doesn't exist
        if (node == null)
            return;

        node.thread = null;

        // Skip cancelled predecessors
        Node pred = node.prev;
        while (pred.waitStatus > 0)
            node.prev = pred = pred.prev;

        // predNext is the apparent node to unsplice. CASes below will
        // fail if not, in which case, we lost race vs another cancel
        // or signal, so no further action is necessary, although with
        // a possibility that a cancelled node may transiently remain
        // reachable.
        Node predNext = pred.next;

        // Can use unconditional write instead of CAS here.
        // After this atomic step, other Nodes can skip past us.
        // Before, we are free of interference from other threads.
        node.waitStatus = Node.CANCELLED;

        // If we are the tail, remove ourselves.
        if (node == tail && compareAndSetTail(node, pred)) {
            pred.compareAndSetNext(predNext, null);
        } else {
            // If successor needs signal, try to set pred's next-link
            // so it will get one. Otherwise wake it up to propagate.
            int ws;
            if (pred != head &&
                ((ws = pred.waitStatus) == Node.SIGNAL ||
                 (ws <= 0 && pred.compareAndSetWaitStatus(ws, Node.SIGNAL))) &&
                pred.thread != null) {
                Node next = node.next;
                if (next != null && next.waitStatus <= 0)
                    pred.compareAndSetNext(predNext, next);
            } else {
                unparkSuccessor(node);
            }

            node.next = node; // help GC  !!!!CONFUSE ME!!!!
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the last line confuse me:

```
node.next = node; // help GC
```

Why don't just set it to null: node.next=null, it also help gc too. Anyone can help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The line "node.next = node;" is used to help the garbage collector (GC) by breaking a potential cycle in the linked list. If "node.next" is set to "null" it would leave a reference to node in next field of the previous node pred which would prevent node from being garbage collected even after it has been removed from the list. By setting "node.next" to node instead, it creates a self-loop, which serves as a clear marker that the node has been removed from the list and is no longer reachable by any other node. When the GC encounters a self-loop it knows that the object can be safely garbage collected.

Setting node.next to null would not be sufficient to break the cycle if there are other references to node in the system. In contrast, setting node.next to node provides a stronger signal to the GC that node is no longer in use, as it creates a unique reference back to node that cannot be shared by any other object.

Comment: 【 If "node.next" is set to "null" it would leave a reference to node in next field of the previous node pred"】what is this mean? is'nt 'pred.next' pointed to [a valid node after arg-'node']  or pointed to null if arg-'node' is tail?

Comment: Yes, you are right but...

the issue with setting node.next to null is that if there are other references to node in the system (e.g., other variables, data structures, or threads), then node would still be reachable through those references, even though it has been removed from the list.

In this case, if node.next were set to null, node would still be referenced by the next field of the pred node, which would prevent node from being garbage collected. This is because the garbage collector only collects objects that are no longer reachable by any live thread or reference in the system.

Comment: "When the GC encounters a self-loop it knows that the object can be safely garbage collected." How do you know it will?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **cross-generational references**, that is, an object in the young gen cannot be collected when an object in the old gen references it.

Please think of this, when a node gets into the old gen, and later it's dequeued, but you haven't set its next pointer to itself or null. Then when the next node gets dequeued, even though it's unreachable, it still cannot be recycled by minor GC since it's linked by the node in the old gen. And things will get worse and worse until a full GC executes, because it will look for both the young gen and the old gen and collect all the objects that is unreachable.

> You can check [this video](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/twitter-services/) starting at minute 23, which illustrates what I mentioned above.

Now we know that it's necessary to cut off the connection to the next node, before it gets dequeued. But why set `node.next` to itself instead of `null`. It is because the `null` value of `node.next` has a special meaning that this node is at the end of the queue.

> As the comment on the property `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.Node#next` goes:
>
> *The next field of cancelled nodes is set to point to the node itself instead of null, to make life easier for isOnSyncQueue.*

**Basically, it's all because of the way the garbage collector works.** It is fine if the minor GC doesn't collect obj1 in the young gen when obj2 in the old gen that links to obj1 is reachable. Because we're still using obj2. But when obj2 is unreachable, if the minor GC still keeps obj1, it would cause troubles and this requires us to know those details of GC to prevent this happening.